# Does Java's foreach loop preserve order?

Tags: java, foreach

Does Java's foreach loop start at the first object and in a linear fashion work it's way to the end? For example

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Zoe", "Bob", "Charlie", "Alex"};
for(String name : names) {
  //do stuff...
}
```

Is the string "Zoe" always processed first, followed by "Bob" etc? No sorting happens? I've tested it out myself and haven't found any but I need a guarantee and couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: short answer: yes, for arrays it does. (a bit) longer answer: depends on the object you iterate over

Comment: @ParkerHalo how about `String`s?

Comment: Question: why should sorting (or any other modification) be applied by just using a loop (no matter if you use foreach or an iterator directly)?

Comment: @Celeritas Maybe my comment was misleading: For ALL arrays (and arraylists) the order is kept intact. For other lists/sets this might not be true!

Comment: For an ordered container, such as an array or a list, items will be iterated in the container's specified order.

Comment: I didn't so much mean "change the order" as in, does it iterate over them in order? For example it wouldn't jump from 0,2,1,3...

Comment: @Thomas and Teo I never claimed they did. I meant process in given order, not sorted order.

Comment: @Celeritas it might do if you are iterating over a collection like a `HashMap`, for which the iteration order is not (necessarily) the insertion order.

Comment: Still the question holds: why should iteration not be in the order provided by the collection/array? As others have already answered iteration order might be determined by the collection (or more precisely its iterator) but it wouldn't make sense for a loop to just "jump around" while just iterating. That would break a lot of logic and would not lead to reliable code.

Comment: @ParkerHalo `For other lists ... this might not be true!` you're right that it _might_ not be true but the definition of a list contains a specified/deterministic order so if it is not true for a certain list I'd not call it a list anymore. :)

Comment: To answer a longstanding question, imagine if you will, an unsorted collection which is backed by a binary tree, and this binary tree kinda has an internal mechanism to optimize itself, like a [scapegoat tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree). Then you might run into instances where the iteration order sorta becomes unpredictable.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes. The order is not changed. This applies to all types of collections of the [Java Collection Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) implementing the [iterator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) that is used by the for-loop. If you want to sort your Array, you can use [Arrays.sort(names)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: also note the semantics of `forEach` change for streams - in this case if you want to guarantee order you will want to use `forEachOrdered`

Answer (score 52):

The enhanced `for` loop is specified in JLS [14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), where its equivalent code is written.

It can be used to loop over arrays and instances of `Iterable`.

- For an array, the order of iteration will be always preserved and be consistent between runs. This is because it is equivalent to a simple `for` loop with an index going from the beginning of the array to its end.

  > The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
  >
  > ```
  > T[] #a = Expression;
  > L1: L2: ... Lm:
  > for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
  >     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
  >     Statement
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > `#a` and `#i` are automatically generated identifiers that are distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope at the point where the enhanced for statement occurs.
- For an `Iterable`, it will follow the order of the corresponding `Iterator` (retrieved by calling [`Iterable.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--)), that may or may not be consistent between runs.

  > The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
  >
  > ```
  > for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
  > {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
  >     (TargetType) #i.next();
  >     Statement
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > `#i` is an automatically generated identifier that is distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3) at the point where the enhanced for statement occurs.

  You should refer to the Javadoc of each type to see if an order is consistent or not. For example, [it is explicitely specified that for `List`, the iterator retains the order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--):

  > Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

  While [it is explicitely specified that for `Set`, the order is unspecified (unless an extra guarantee is made)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator--):

  > The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).